# Running Pretty Dropdown on dynamic selects

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, select, dropdown

I'm using Pretty Dropdowns (https://www.npmjs.com/package/pretty-dropdowns) for my dropdowns, and I have a form that allows the user to append lines to the form. The lines they're adding also contain dropdowns, but I need Pretty Dropdowns to run again so it can be applied to the new dropdowns.

Here's my jquery:

```
$('#addEmployee').click(function(){

    var empLines = $("div[id^='employee']").length;

    if(empLines < 21) {
      $('#employees').append('<div id="employee'+ id +'" class="emp-wrap row"><div class="form-group quarter-group"><label for="empClass'+ id +'">Employee Classification:</label><select class="form-control" id="empClass'+ id +'" name="empClass[]" required><option value="Full-time Employee">Full-time Employee</option><option value="Manager">Manager</option><option value="Owner">Owner</option></select></div></div>');}
      removeEmployee();
    id++;
});
```

I've tried adding `$('select').prettyDropdown();` inside the function and outside the function with no luck. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run `prettyDropdown` method with `id`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$dropdown = $('select').prettyDropdown();
  
});

var id=1;
$('#addEmployee').click(function(){
   var empLines =0;

    if(empLines < 21) {
      $('#employees').append('<div id="employee'+ id +'" class="emp-wrap row"><div class="form-group quarter-group"><label for="empClass'+ id +'">Employee Classification:</label><select class="form-control" id="empClass'+ id +'" name="empClass[]" required><option value="Full-time Employee">Full-time Employee</option><option value="Manager">Manager</option><option value="Owner">Owner</option></select></div></div>');}
      
      $('#empClass'+id).prettyDropdown()
      //removeEmployee();
    id++;
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/prettydropdowns.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://thdoan.github.io/pretty-dropdowns/js/jquery.prettydropdowns.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://thdoan.github.io/pretty-dropdowns/css/prettydropdowns.css">


<select>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>
<div>

<br/>
</div>
<div id="employees">
</div>

<input type="button" id="addEmployee" value="addEmployee" />
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks! :)